# Prove by induction that $\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot k! = (n+1)!-1$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that $$\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot k! = (n+1)!-1$$

I cannot manage to proceed after assuming that the equality works for $p$.

Comment: Note you can prove using telescoping series since $k\cdot k!=(k+1)!-k!$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1}k\cdot k!=(1+1)!-1$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot k!=(n+1)!-1$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}k\cdot k!=$

$\color\red{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot k!}+(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!=$

$\color\red{(n+1)!-1}+(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!=$

$(n+1)!\cdot(n+2)-1=$

$(n+2)!-1=$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: Back at it again with the induction proofs `;-)`

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: if it ain't broke...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the desired equality holds for some fixed $n$. We'll show it holds for $n+1$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}k\cdot k! &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot k! + (n+1)\cdot(n+1)!\\
&=(n+1)!-1+(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!\\
&=(1+n+1)(n+1)!-1\\
&=(n+2)\cdot(n+1)!-1\\
&=(n+2)!-1.
\end{aligned}
$$